# Does the JPEG file format support RGB data?

Tags: jpeg, image-processing

I am doing some programming that involves encoding image data using WIC.  I used RGB data but WIC always treats it as BGR.  I have a [related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737917/forcing-to-wic-to-treat-image-data-as-rgb) dealing with the programming side.  However, I want to rule out that the problem could relate to WIC or the JPEG file format.

Is that normal behavior for a JPEG, or how WIC treats the image data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This is a major rewrite of my answer based on additional information provided by the OP in comments, the related thread on SO, and his own answer.*

> Does the JPEG file format support RGB data?

RGB has two meanings.

1. It is a color space, where colors are defined in terms of the primary colors of red, green. and blue.  The JPEG standard is based on the RGB color space as a starting point.  It is converted to YCbCr for compression purposes.  A pretty thorough description of the encoding and compression process is given in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).
2. RGB signifies an order for interpreting the stored color data.  Bob's answer explains why it can also be interpreted in BGR order.  This is the meaning that caused the confusion leading to this question.  It actually relates not to the JPEG standard, but to how WIC handles the data.

An image format file specification includes defining the color sequence.  That isn't the situation in this case.  WIC is creating a JPEG from raw image data.  According to the link you found, WIC supports both RGB and BGR order for the input data, although it lists only BGR as input for its native JPEG Codec.  So the issue is interfacing with WIC and feeding it what it expects to see.

Comment: Oops! sorry, not GBR its BGR(updated the question). thanks for your help. and here is my original question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737917/forcing-to-wic-to-treat-image-data-as-rgb

Comment: @mhs: So it looks like a programming issue?  You accepted the answer on the SO question and commented that it was working, so it isn't clear what you're asking on SU.  Are you just trying to rule out an issue related to WIC or JPEG?

Comment: yes my program works now(so i accepted the answer). but still can't understand why not RGB data.

Comment: I suspect it is in giving WIC what it expects to see.  If it's working now, it has to be in the coding you changed.  Sounds like a problem interfacing with WIC.  It might take somebody at Microsoft to explain why WIC performs in the way it did based on your previous code.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with OpenGL compatibility... Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space on the RGBA Byte Order paragraph and sources.

Comment: @AlexMazzariol Quite apart from OpenGL: some things (CPUs, programs, protocols, specs) use little-endian, some use big-endian. It just happens that the Device Independent Bitmap format uses little-endian, and is the typical in-memory representation of uncompressed image data is normally a DIB. This was actually before OpenGL 1.0 was released - while the two may be related, OpenGL is probably not the cause.

Answer (score 5):

While the actual data format read by WIC can be controlled, notice that the [Device Independent Bitmap](http://www.herdsoft.com/ti/davincie/imex3j8i.htm) format, commonly used for uncompressed image data (and contained inside most BMP files too), stores each pixel in 24BPP and 32BPP formats as a single 24-bit or 32-bit [**little-endian**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) word.

This image describes little-endian quite well:

[image]

<sup>Image is public domain, by [R. S. Shaw](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:R._S._Shaw) and sourced from [Wikimedia Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Little-Endian.svg)</sup>

As you can see, the least-significant byte comes first and the most-significant byte comes last. A 32BPP ARGB value would be stored in memory and on disk as the individual 8-bit bytes B, G, R, A. The same goes for a 24BPP RGB value, stored in memory as B, G, R.

This likely explains why the default format used by WIC seems to be "BGR" - because that's the default in-memory representation, and conversion to big-endian RGB would be additional work that isn't done unless explicitly requested.

Incidentally, humans normally read numbers as big-endian; in the opposite order. The big-endian byte representation of the same 24BPP/32BPP word would read as RGB or ARGB, closer to what you seem to expect.

Comment: so that means,  on little endian system.

image → memory →　image 

will switch channels

Answer (score 1):

[This forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4e0a03b1-67db-4c36-949b-c49ec5a212d5/wic-treat-input-data-as-bgr?forum=windowswic&prof=required) says,

> This is covered on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797.aspx#jpeg__native_codec). The JPEG encoder encodes three formats:
>
> - GUID_WICPixelFormat8bppGray
> - GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR
> - GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppCMYK
>
> If your source data is in a different format, you need to use
>   IWICFormatConverter as part of your chain.

Comment: Good find.  When all else fails, read the manual.  :-)  Thanks for posting this.